# Errors at Imports in ActivityThread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, import

I am working on a Game when suddenly this Errormsg showed up.
The Error appears in the ActivityThread from API 20 and shows that some .jars which it want to import don´t even exist...

I have no Idea what i am doing wrong..:

```
  10-19 07:21:12.465    1225-1225/com.example.markus.testingapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.markus.testingapp, PID: 1225
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.markus.testingapp/com.example.markus.testingapp.Testlayout}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
            at com.example.markus.testingapp.Testlayout.<init>(Testlayout.java:18)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 07:21:16.525    1225-1225/com.example.markus.testingapp I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1225 SIG: 9
```

And here is my Grade.build if u need it:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.markus.testingapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

UPDATE!!!:

Found out that this code causes troubles:

```
public class Testlayout extends Activity {

    public data player = new data();
    public ProgressBar pb_autofreq = (ProgressBar) (findViewById(R.id.pb_autofreq));
    public TextView tv_autohacker_freqstat = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.tV_autohacker_freqstat));
    public ProgressBar pb_startup = (ProgressBar) (findViewById(R.id.pb_startup));
    public int cases;
```

Whats wrong with it?
Hope you can help me,

thanks and greets

Markus

Comment: *testingapp.Testlayout.<init>(Testlayout.java:18)*

Comment: Whats wrong with this?

Comment: how am I supposed to know it?

Comment: Cant find an error there...

Comment: Problem Solved: I am not allowed to declare Widgets in a class? Only in functions? Thx